# Make LEFT JOIN query more efficient

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

The following query with LEFT JOIN is drawing too much memory (~4GB), but the host only allows about 120MB for this process.

```
SELECT grades.grade, grades.evaluation_id, evaluations.evaluation_name, evaluations.value, evaluations.maximum FROM grades LEFT JOIN evaluations ON grades.evaluation_id = evaluations.evaluation_id WHERE grades.registrar_id = ?
```

Create table syntax for grades:

```
  CREATE TABLE `grades` (
  `grade_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `evaluation_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `registrar_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`grade_id`),
  KEY `registrarGrade_key` (`registrar_id`),
  KEY `evaluationKey` (`evaluation_id`),
  KEY `grades_id_index` (`grade_id`),
  KEY `eval_id_index` (`evaluation_id`),
  KEY `grade_index` (`grade`),
  CONSTRAINT `evaluationKey` FOREIGN KEY (`evaluation_id`) REFERENCES `evaluations` (`evaluation_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `registrarGrade_key` FOREIGN KEY (`registrar_id`) REFERENCES `registrar` (`reg_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1627 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

evaluations table:

```
CREATE TABLE `evaluations` (
      `evaluation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `instance_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `evaluation_col` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `evaluation_name` longtext,
      `evaluation_method` enum('class','email','online','lab') DEFAULT NULL,
      `evaluation_deadline` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `maximum` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`evaluation_id`),
      KEY `instanceID_key` (`instance_id`),
      KEY `eval_name_index` (`evaluation_name`(3)),
      KEY `eval_method_index` (`evaluation_method`),
      KEY `eval_deadline_index` (`evaluation_deadline`),
      KEY `maximum` (`maximum`),
      KEY `value_index` (`value`),
      KEY `eval_id_index` (`evaluation_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `instanceID_key` FOREIGN KEY (`instance_id`) REFERENCES `course_instance` (`instance_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The Php code to pull the data:

```
$sql = "SELECT grades.grade, grades.evaluation_id, evaluations.evaluation_name, evaluations.value, evaluations.maximum FROM grades LEFT JOIN evaluations ON grades.evaluation_id = evaluations.evaluation_id WHERE grades.registrar_id = ? AND YEAR(entry_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
                    $result = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                    if($result === FALSE)
                        die($mysqli->error);
                    $result->bind_param('i',$reg_ids[$i]);
                    $result->execute();
                    $result->bind_result($grade, $eval_id, $evalname, $evalval, $max);
                    while($result->fetch()){
```

And the fatal error message

[image]

Is there a way to drastically reduce the memory load on this query?

Thanks!

1. Curiously, changing the MySQL query did not change the amount of memory attempted to be allocated

Comment: How many rows in the tables (approximately)?

Comment: fewer than 100 in the evaluation table, but over 1000 in the grades table (and quickly growing)

Comment: Unless you have some really large entries in the 'longtext' column then, even if the tables were loaded into memory, i suspect it would only occupy a few MB. Are you doing any other processing?

Comment: hm that's puzzling. There isn't a large amount of information in the longtext fields. php throws a fatal error on this line. There are a few very basic calls before this point.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some loop in the code that, in effect, is calling this query a lot and it not completing? To debug that situation then put an _echo `__FILE__.__LINE__;`_ before the 'execute' statement - you should only see the echo once.

Comment: Yes the echo only came up once

Comment: Can you post all your php code? If it is large (more than a couple of hundred lines) then i suggest you put it in [Pastebin or equivalent](http://pastebin.com/) and add the 'url' to your question. I cannot see anything obvious with what you have supplied that will cause such large amounts of memory to used.

Comment: As an aside, it's really unlikely that you would want to use FLOAT for any value in these tables. DECIMAL seems more plausible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; I want to see if you have anything like these:

grades: `INDEX(registration_id)`

evaluations: `PRIMARY KEY(evaluation_id)`

**Edit**

You now have redundant indexes in both table -- probably because of my suggestion.  That is, you already have both the indexes that would help with the query.

Since you have LONGTEXT and it is trying to allocate exactly 4GB, the max size of LONGTEXT, I guess that is the problem.  Suggest you ALTER that column to be TEXT (64KB max) or MEDIUMTEXT (16MB max).  I have not seen this behavior before in PHP, but then I rarely use anything bigger than TEXT.

Comment: Amazing you nailed it! Changing the field to MEDIUMTEXT solved the problem. Yes, your suspicion is correct -- it was your reply that prompted me to index the columns. I'll read up on indexing.