# How to access a stream of a BLOB?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

Is there any working method to access a BLOB as a stream? I just found out the hard way that [PDO's implementation is broken](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913) since 8 years.

Comment: I suspect this is more interesting than i thought. I was trying to assist someone who was reading large 'blobs' from a mysql database months ago. They had memory issues and i couldn't understand why. Someone suggested using mediumtext. The OP reported that it all worked. I did not understand why and it has puzzled me. I have just searched the 'net. Mysql buffers the blob in memory before sending it out. Large blobs means lots of memory as buffers.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "mysql buffers the blob in memory". This is actually what I want to avoid be using a streaming API.

Comment: Sadly, no reference for PHP. I cannot find any useful reference for streaming blobs from a mysql database which is interesting in itself. I hope i have just missed something obvious.

Comment: Here is the actual question that I found 'interesting': [Make LEFT JOIN query more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191239/make-left-join-query-more-efficient#comment46596761_29191239). I came second - with no idea why at the time.